# Horizontally centering a div inside another div - no scrollbars allowed

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div which has several child divs in a row. The total width of the child divs is more than the width of the parent div and my screen. I would like the text "CENTERED X CENTERED" to be horizontally centered. I do not want a scrollbar to be displayed. I must use white-space:nowrap.

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow:hidden; text-align:center">
  <div style="display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center">
  <div style="display:inline-block">My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text...</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">CENTERED X CENTERED</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text...</div>
</div>
```

How could I modify my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use an extra div? The outer most is overflow:hidden, so make the extra div super wide - wider than the content will ever be. You can then center it using some clever CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/5cvujqd3/

#### Basic structure

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- inline-block stuff here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

### And some CSS

```
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}
.inner {
  width: 10000em; /*super wide*/
  margin-left: -5000em; /*half the width*/
  background: #cbb;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform:translateX()`, `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:hidden;`

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent > div {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.parent > div > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text...</div>
    <div>CENTERED X CENTERED</div>
    <div>My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text... My text...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```